Test client connection with Kafka Broker using Kafkajs with SASL Authentication
I have a use case where I want to provide a dashboard to my users where they can enter their Kafka Broker details and check the connectivity before using them in the product.
Basic connectivity check works fine with the below code:
  const kafka = new Kafka({
    brokers: ['localhost:9092']
  });


  const admin = kafka.admin();
  try {
    await admin.connect();
    console.log('Connected to Kafka broker successfully!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to connect to Kafka broker:', error);
  } finally {
    await admin.disconnect();
  }


I have 2 concerns here:

If the admin operations are disabled by the user on their kafka
cluster then these admin operations might fail and admin.connect() might not work as expected.
If SASL Authentication is configured, this admin.connect() works whether I provide credentials or not. Only when I try to produce a message is when I receive Failed to connect to Kafka broker: KafkaJSNonRetriableError

In the system that I am building it's possible that I am not allowed to create topics or product messages to the kafka broker but only allowed to consume or vice versa.
The only solution I can come up with is to take the topic name input from the user during testing of connection to whom I can either produce or consume a message and test the connectivity in that way.
Please suggest if there's a better way to test connectivity without producing or consuming a message? Also, if someone can explain why does admin.connect() work even without credentials after enabling SASL Plain Authentication on the broker?
I am attaching a snippet of my code which is used to test the connection right now where I create a random topic and try to produce a message to it to test the connectivity.
            const kafka = new Kafka({
                brokers: brokers,
                ...(connectionDto.ssl && { ssl: connectionDto.ssl }),
                ...(connectionDto.authentication && { sasl: {
                  mechanism: "plain", // scram-sha-256 or scram-sha-512
                  username: connectionDto.username,
                  password: connectionDto.password
                }}),
              });
              
            const admin = kafka.admin();
            try {

              // Connecting to the Kafka broker
              await admin.connect();
              console.log('Connected to Kafka broker successfully!');
              const producer = kafka.producer()

              await producer.connect()
              await producer.send({
                  topic: 'test1',
                  messages: [
                      { key: 'name', value: 'hello world' }
                  ],
              })
              await admin.disconnect();
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Failed to connect to Kafka broker:', error);
            } 

